# How to repeat or "restart" a while statement?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, python-2.x

Here is what I'm trying to do, I'm making a text adventure game. The player has to make a choice to go on the path going backwards, right, or left. If the player picks left, they walk in a loop around a tree and they're back where they started. **I'm trying to make it so after the player picks "left", the `while` statement "restarts" so they have to pick to go left, right, or backwards again.** Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is the code:

```
import os

# Setup
yes_no = ["yes", "no"]
directions = ["left", "right", "forward", "backward"]

# Name
name = raw_input("What is your name, camper? ")
os.system("clear")

# Story Introduction
print ("It's the last night of RV camping with your family in the big forest. Your family has decided to go on a walk to see the nice stars in the night sky. As you follow your family, you drop your flashlight in the bushes. When you go back to the path, you're completly turned around and you have no clue where your family went.\n")
print ("When you return to the path, it splits into 2! Which way do you think your family went " + name + "?")

response = ""
while response not in directions:
  response = raw_input("\nleft/right/backwards\n")
  if response == "left":
        os.system("clear")
        print("You head down the left path. You past by a tree that's cut down. You continue further down the path. After about 2 minutes of walking, you past by the same cut down tree. You just walked in a circle! You walk back to the fork in the path. Which way do you go?\n ")
  elif response == "right":
        os.system("clear")
        print("You head down the right path. The night is getting darker...\n ")
  elif response == "backwards":
        os.system("clear")
        print("You head down the path behind you. You hear a crunching noise. As you get closer, you see your family's RV! It turns out, you left a pile of chips on your camping chair outside. Uh oh, a bear is eating those chips! Farewell camper, you got eaten by the bear...\n\n You got: The Bear Ending")
        quit()
  else:
        print("\n\n\n\nI didn't understand that. Please type one of the following:")
```

Comment: how about put the while loop in a function and called it when the player pick left ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a new while before you actual while, so when a player choose a path, you can restart it

Something like this:

```
    i=2
while i < n: #n could be any number
    if something:
       do something
       i += 1
    else: 
       do something else  
       i = 2 #restart the loop`
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it would be to to nest the `while` loop you have in an outer one, because that will allow you to `break` out of the inner one, and depending on the `done` flag, either restart the inner one again or quit. Here's what I mean:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68877534/how-to-repeat-or-restart-a-while-statement

import os

def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')  # Command depends on OS.

# Setup
yes_no = ["yes", "no"]
directions = ["left", "right", "forward", "backward"]

# Name
name = raw_input("What is your name, camper? ")
clear_screen()

# Story Introduction
print("It's the last night of RV camping with your family in the big forest. Your family "
      "has decided to go on a walk to see the nice stars in the night sky. As you follow "
      "your family, you drop your flashlight in the bushes. When you go back to the path,"
      " you're completly turned around and you have no clue where your family went.\n")
print("When you return to the path, it splits into 2! Which way do you think your family "
      "went " + name + "?")

done = False
while not done:
    response = ""
    while response not in directions:
        response = raw_input("\nleft/right/backwards\n")
        if response == "left":
            clear_screen()
            print("You head down the left path. You past by a tree that's cut down. You "
                  "continue further down the path. After about 2 minutes of walking, you "
                  "pass by the same cut down tree. You just walked in a circle! You walk "
                  "back to the fork in the path. Which way do you go?\n")
            break  # Start over.
        elif response == "right":
            clear_screen()
            print("You head down the right path. The night is getting darker...\n ")
        elif response == "backwards":
            clear_screen()
            print("You head down the path behind you. You hear a crunching noise. As you "
                  "get closer, you see your family's RV! It turns out, you left a pile "
                  "of chips on your camping chair outside. Uh oh, a bear is eating those "
                  "chips! Farewell camper, you got eaten by the bear...\n\n You got: The "
                  "Bear Ending")
            done = True
            break
        else:
            print("\n\n\n\nI didn't understand that. Please type one of the following:")
```